# how to disable multiple touches on view hierarchy?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, touch

In my iPad app..

Developing dragging and dropping..

Everything works fine in simulator as in simulator there is only one touch of mouse pointer...

But in device everything gets stucked because of **multiple touches...**

In my iPad app,

```
View contains scrollview and scroll view contaains cells...
I have done 
user interaction disabled
on touches began

and 
user interaction Enabled
on touches Ended
```

Though it allows touches..

I have also done **multiple touch disabled** for all views

Please help I am stucked....

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming from your question you want to disable multiple touches on your views. To do this, just use the `multipleTouchEnabled` property, like so: `self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = NO`. Don't forget to iterate through all your views and sub-views to set this property.

Next time, maybe take a look at Apple's own documentation, because it's quite good and the `multipleTouchEnabled` bool is standard across all UIView subclasses.

Comment: `multipleTouchEnabled` disables multiple touches on the view it's applied to. If you're still able to use multi-touch then you more than likely haven't applied it to all your subviews, or your problems aren't related to multiple touches at all